# iPhone :: Objective-C - Loading a list of Images from Restful Webservice into UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Hihi all,

I have implement a mechanism for the above (in the question title), this is how it works:

1. Create an NSURLConnection and make a call to my json webservice to get a list of records with the image URL for each of the record.
2. In the connectionDidFinishLoading delegate, I set the returned records to my NSArray and  reload my UITableView with the NSArray, but I don't load the image at this point.
3. In the same connectionDidFinishLoading delegate, for each of the retrieved record, I fire off separate connection to get the image data. Imagine I have 5 records returned from the previous json webservice, I will fire off 5 GET requests to get my image data for each of the records.
4. Then this time round, in the connectionDidFinishLoading delegate, I will know this time it is fired from the request of getting image data, I will set the image data into my NSArray of my UITableView datasource and do a reloadData. For 5 records, the table will be reloaded 5 times.
5. Everything seems working fine only if I do not reload the last 2 elements of my NSArray, otherwise, I will hit the exc_bad_access exception.

Appreciate your kind advice. This might be a foolish way of doing thing.

:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you describe what you are doing seems OK. You could be using reloadRowsAtIndexPaths to just update each cell as its image is received rather than the whole table.

[Here's a stack overflow question that may be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1130089/189804). Searching for lazy loading will get you plenty more examples.

I think using Core Data is the right way to do this because it lets you use a NSFetchedResultsController to handle all the table maintenance for you. Initially you load a table with objects that have a nil image path attribute so your cellForRowAtIndexPath can display a placeholder (or nothing). When you get a returned image (asynchronously) you write the image to local storage and update Core Data with the path for the image that should be displayed for that record. When you make a change to core data you do a performFetch on the fetched results controller and your table is displayed correctly. If you follow [Apple's sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) you don't even need a reloadData on the table.

Comment: Thanks for the input! Will certainly try that! :)

Comment: Thanks for the information for the lazy loading, but my issue is nothing to do with the loading, it's that I made a little memory alloc mistake when I initialize my image placeholder to the UIImage during the first load. :)

Comment: And I have followed your advice to use reloadRowsAtIndexPaths method to avoid the reloadData the whole tableView. :)