# AFnetworking Vs dispatch_aync() Vs SDWebImage Framework

Tags: ios, afnetworking, sdwebimage

I am new to iOS programing.

I have a requirement where I have to do server calls many times giving large JSON and then parsing and showing in `TableView`/`Collection`/`View` `Controllers`.

And I have to download Images inside `Collection Grid View` and `UITableView`, thereby starting/cancelling downloading of images on user scrolling.

So

Q1) For image downloading in Table View/Grid View I am thinking to use Apple Table Lazy Loading Sample + replacing Icon Downloader with that of `SDWebImage` as mentioned here in link several problem in that Apple sample and via `SDWebImage` I can config `cache` as per my requirement.

**EDIT:** Basically I would like to have a very transparent way to get images from a url, so first look for them in a NSCache, if not found look on disk (or Core Data)l if not found again download async and then again save in cache as well.I guess SDWebImage provides this but for AFNetworking i have to look inside code and modify it.

[iOS lazy-loading of table images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14400378/ios-lazy-loading-of-table-images)

Q2) For server calls and `JSON` parsing, whether I should go for using `dispatch_async` and then parse `JSON` using `NSJSONSerialization` or I should go for using `AFNetworking` for this

Disadvantage of using `AFNetworking` lib is that I need only server call and parsing no other functionality..and for this reason if I would be going for this lib this would increase app size by 1.4 MB as I am already adding `SDWebImage` framework (>3 MB).

This is what I found after lot of googling.
Please suggest if I am missing something...and any other approach I should follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AFNetworking` is better and can handle your both problems. You can also use it for parsing as well as for image download. It can cache even and will never go to server again and again if same image is requested by an image view. Use `UImageView` category provided in `AFNetworking`.

**Edit**
Caching in Afnetworking read posts in [this](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/pull/1136) submisison. 
If you don't want to use full functionality of AFNetworking and just want to download data, I wills suggest you don't use it, You can do this all with `NSURSession`, Don't add dependency in your project. Use `NSURLSession` its strong an can do better for you.  YOu just need only one `NSJSONSerilization` call to parse data to `NSObject`, that is not to big deal.

```
NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                         completionHandler:
     ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
         // ...
     }];

 [task resume];
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this info.But i have a doubt that can we config Cache in AFNetworking as per our requirement?

Comment: What are your requirement... You can even extend that, to move cache to disk or whatever changes you want to do...

Comment: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/pull/1136 read this link you will find some interesting caching discussion.

Comment: Thanks for info C_X, but i decided to go for SDWebImage via following this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8703877/is-there-a-framework-for-image-caching-on-ios?rq=1. Can you please look into this?.
Thanks

Comment: SDWebImage is also very good API, You will be including more dependencies.. Otherwise it fine. Now if you are not using full AFNetworking functionality, Why not you start using NSURLSession to download JSON data, that's is also an option.