# TableView with Lazy loading in mac osx

Tags: xcode, macos

I started mac osx development and I want to integrate lazy loading in tableview I searched but I did not find any example. I tried to implement ios lazy loading in mac osx but it does not work.

Any body know how to implement lazy loading in NSTableview.

Thanks,
Yen

Comment: That's great, but have you tried anything on your own yet?

Comment: I did lazy loading in iPhone app so many times and I used that logic in mac osx,but it does not work.

Comment: Hi yen  ,                                                                       u can check this apple link and can download the project                           check this thread also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130089/lazy-load-images-in-uitableview/1829035#1829035

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue using AFNetworking.