# ScrollView sensitivity iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, performance, uiscrollview

how to reduce the speed of ScrollView.

because of a problem with images in the TableView out of order. I want to make the Scroll slower
or can also be (if possible) it stops faster

Comment: What problems are you having with images?  If the tableview is sluggish because of images being loaded then you're better off loading those images in the background instead of forcing the tableview scrolling to slow down.

Comment: I was told this, by the way how is it?

Comment: Have a look at this question for lazy loading images: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130089/lazy-load-images-in-uitableview

Comment: I know .. I did a NSOperationqueue but I wanted to do so in the background (you can help?)

Comment: Read the answers to the question I posted above.  Specifically have a look at this sample code: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can't slow down the scrollviews scrolling speed. It would probably feel quite awkward too, because the user is accustomed to move the content around as he would, for example, move around a piece of paper on on a table with his finger.

What you can do however is making the scrollview decelerating quickly, which means it would not keep scrolling or would even stop immediately after the touch ends. (See `decelerationRate` property of [UIScrollView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html))

Another option would be placing another view atop of your scrollview and let it intercept all touch events, so you have the opportunity to choose the ratio between finger movement and content movement according to your needs. This would be quite tedious though, since you would have to implement all the bouncing, inertia movement and - most important - telling scrolling events from other actions and pass them to the interface elements below.