# IOS image is not set in an image view

Tags: ios, uiimageview, tablecell

I am using the same code in two of my view controllers (they are implementing the same class what changes is the url they download) and in one occassion the image is displayed correclty while in the other I do see an empty cell.

Here is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier=@"MyCell";
    //this is the identifier of the custom cell
    MyCell *cell = (MyCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    tableView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    tableView.opaque=NO;
    tableView.backgroundView=nil;

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    NSLog(@"Image url is:%@",[images_url objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
    NSURL *url_image=[NSURL URLWithString:[images_url objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    cell.myimage.image=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url_image]];


    return cell;
}
```

As i told you I have 2 view controllers implementing the same class. In the view did load the url is set depending on the value of a flag. If I open controller A, I see no image, if I open  view B i can see the image. Both of the urls are correct as I can check it with the NSLog I have inserted.

What might be the problem?

Comment: Are you running this on iOS 6, and if so have you registered `MyCell` with the tableview using `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:` in both table views?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately calling "NSData dataWithContentsOfURL" is a blocking call.  Execution of your program will stop until iOS is able to fetch all the data from the server or fails trying.  This may often be "fast" if you're on LTE or WiFi; but can potentially take a LONG time.

Meanwhile, you're on the "main thread" in your app - so your app will appear to freeze-up, and the system's watchdog timer may kill your app.  If anyone besides you will use this ap, you absolutely need to populate your tableview cell's image with local data that's retrieved immediately or use asynchronous methods.

Just google for "lazy load UIImage".  This SO question has some good tips on the subject:
[lazy-load-images-in-uitableview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130089/lazy-load-images-in-uitableview)

Additionally, you should move these lines to some setup code.  You don't need to perform them every time to update a cell:

```
tableView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
tableView.opaque=NO;
tableView.backgroundView=nil;
```

Best of luck!