# Getting images from JSON

Tags: ios, image, tableview, restkit

I'm using RestKit in my project, and was wondering the best way to pull **images from the JSON** into the `UITableView` cells.

JSON response:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2013-05-10T03:09:39Z",
    "resultsOffset": 0,
    "status": "success",
    "resultsLimit": 10,
    "breakingNews": [],
    "resultsCount": 393,
    "feed": [{
        "headline": "Headline text",
        "lastModified": "2013-05-08T14:55:03Z",
        "description": "Description text.",
        "images": [{
            "height": 324,
            "alt": "",
            "width": 576,
            "name": "The Name",
            "caption": "Debate it.",
            "url": "http://a.website.com/media/motion/2013/0508/dm_130508_debate/dm_130508_debate.jpg"
        }],
```

Is there a good way in RestKit to do it, or should I use AFNetworking, or is some other way better?

I can post extra code snippets on how I already am pulling the `headline/description/lastModified`.  I have a `Feed` model set up right now for that.  From what I can understand, getting the image `url` is slightly different tho.

Need...
[image]

... to have Image
[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130089/lazy-load-images-in-uitableview?lq=1

Comment: AFNetworking and UIImageWeb both have UIImageView categories for asynchronous loading of images.

Comment: @Rob Thanks for the quick response!  Have a recommendation on which one is easier to use in your experience?

Comment: @Thilo Thanks for the link, I think I've come across that before and I'll look into using it since it seems like alot of people use it.  If you have any personal experience and have a specific recommendation too let me know.  Thx!

Comment: @Rob Awesome, thanks for the detailed suggestion, appreciate it!

Comment: @Reez. They're both one line calls to UIImageView categories. As seamless as painless as can be. `AFNetworking` is more of a generalized networking solution, and `SDWebImage` is more special purpose solution. (And in a correction to my earlier comment, both handle caches well.) But given that you're using `RESTKit` (and therefore don't need most of AFNetworking), perhaps `SDWebImage`'s focus on image processing, maybe that's a more logical choice.

Comment: @Rob Cool, I am trying out `SDWebImage` right now, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)
for Asynchronous download and cache images.
It works perfect for me.

Answer (score 1):

you can use async imageview which will the display the image from URL, you can use the following https://github.com/enormego/EGOImageLoading/tree/master/EGOImageView