# Can we embed UIScrollView in UITableViewController while using storyboards?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I just want to keep `Tableview` and it cells inside the `UIScrollView` but my problem it is `UITableViewController` so I can't able embed scroll to the controller....Please provide me solution for this..(It's using Storyboards).

Comment: but why?? uitableview is subclass of uiscrollview..

Comment: @Virussmca I have disabled scrolling of uitableview..because i am loading some images from web so its hanging while scrolling table scrolls ..so i want to embed scrollview ...

Comment: if you want to load images from web  why are you not using [Lazy load images in UITableView](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1130089/1597744)?