# passing the data from uiscrollview with pagecontroller to another viewcontroller

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I have a scrollview of images, I will like to tab them and will pushed to another view.

once i tab on the image, the whole view should push to another view.
this my `ScrollView.h` as the following

```
@interface PeekPagedScrollViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIPageControl *pageControl;

@end
```

and this is my images array as follow

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Set up the image you want to scroll & zoom and add it to the scroll view
    self.pageImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"photo1.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"photo2.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"photo3.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"photo4.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"photo5.png"],
                       nil];
```

so what i need when user touch the photo go to another detailViewController; for example if selected Photo1 this photo enlarge on another viewcontroller
so if anybody knows the solution or suitable tutorial

Comment: so you want us to write logic completely. rather you should show some code where you have struck

Comment: Provide some code, it's not clear where you are stuck, Please specify?

Comment: please see the below code

Comment: i post some code above; so please help me or if you know a suitable tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the `UIScrollView`, set the `delegate` yourself and then this method should give you the index of the tapped image:

```
- (void)singleTapGestureCaptured:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture{

    CGPoint touchPoint = [gesture locationInView:<yourScrollView>];

    NSUInteger touchedPage = floorf(touchPoint.x / <yourScrollView>.frame.size.width);
    if ([<arrayOfImages> count>] > 1) {

        touchedPage = touchedPage % ([<arrayOfImages> count] - 1);
    }

    NSLog(@"Touched page: %d", touchedPage);

    //Use touchedPage and push the next view controller here

}
```

To add the gesture recognizer, add these lines into `viewDidLoad` (or you can use the IB):

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTapGestureCaptured:)];
[<yourScrollView> addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

Comment: please can you told me how to import uitapgesturerecognizer; or which framework i can import

Comment: @MohamedReda Edited my answer, no need to add a framework

Comment: please i stuck again to how pass the image to the second view i try to put this code on viewDidload `[imageView setImage:chosenImage];` or `self.selectedImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:self.imageView];` but it's not work; can you help me

Comment: Define a property (a UIImage or UIImageView) called selectedImage for DetailViewController.h file. Then using the code I give you set the selected image like detailViewController.selectedImage = [<arrayOfImages> objectAtIndex:touchedPage]; and push the new view controller. Now you can use the _selectedImage inside DetailViewController.m file.

Comment: i use on viewDidload method the following code `//self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:self.selectedImage]` but not working; this is correct

Comment: please the final question; i know i make headache for you but the animation is very slow; there's solution for that

Comment: Sorry, which animation is slow here? I only posted code for finding the index of the selected image. But other than that you can use the image anyway you want in DetailVC.

Comment: when i press the image to go to another view the transition is slow

Comment: when i push the view controller i put this code `PassTouchesViewController *ptvc = [[PassTouchesViewController alloc] init];
    ptvc.selectedImage = [imageArray objectAtIndex:touchedPage];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:ptvc animated:YES];` so i mentioned animated:yes; so there's a mistake on this

Comment: well, setting a property wont slow down the pushing animation, there is another reason for that. You have to look it up by " push vc animation slow" or performance issue on pushing vc. etc. It is not related to selecting an image or setting a property.

Answer (score 1):

Better use `UITableView` and load all images in `UITableViewCell` using lazy loading, and when  you select any image then `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` will give you index for selected image and in this way you can navigate and pass data from one viewController to nextViewController.

Refer [Lazy load images in UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130089/lazy-load-images-in-uitableview)

Comment: are you know tutorial explain that

Comment: I have update my answer.Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Better use UITableview or GMGridView for this example code following.

```
[theApp.fullViewModeObject.statusDicts addObjectsFromArray:statusDicts];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:theApp.fullViewModeObject animated:YES];
```

theApp.fullViewModeObject is fullviewmode class object
[theApp.fullViewModeObject.statusDicts] is array for loading image details

Comment: can you check the code posted; and can you give me more detail